# Second order partial derivative chain rule?

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule, change-of-variable

So let's say I have a second order partial derivative of a function with respect to $t$. Now I define 
                               $$T=t + f(r)$$ 
and require $\partial_t^2$ as a function of $\partial_r^2$ and $\partial_T^2$.

Is the second order chain rule for ordinary derivatives applicable here? Or is there any other formula that needs to be applied?

**Edit**: For some $\phi(t)$, I have attempted the following calculations based on Ted Shifrin's comment
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial T} + f'(r)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial T}\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[f'(r)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right]$$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial T^2} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} + f''(r)\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}\right) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + f'(r) \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial t }\right)$$

Comment: The answer will also involve $\partial_r$. Note that $\partial_t = \partial_T  + f'(r)\partial_r$ by the usual (two-variable) chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you take a look at my edit and tell me if I got it right?

Comment: Nope. There were special things in that question due to having just a linear change of coordinates.  Use what I gave you and differentiate again.

Comment: @TedShifrin     I've redone the calculation starting with what you gave. Did I get it right this time?

Comment: @TedShifrin Also, I'm assuming the relation you've given me is for $t= T + f(r)$. If so, I will just change my original question to that.

Comment: But you changed it wrong, didn't you? Moreover, the calculation is incorrect. The answer should be $$\partial_t^2 = \partial_T^2 + f'(r)^2\partial_r^2 + f'(r)f''(r)\partial_r.$$ I'm leaving town for a few days and won't be checking in for a while. I think you need some basic practice with the chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin    No, I haven't changed it yet. And I'm having trouble seeing how you've arrived at that. I really do need some practice with the chain rule. Thanks for your help

Comment: @TedShifrin    Okay I see my mistake now. I was trying to take a(n incorrect) shortcut. Again, thanks for your comment